# Perl map block local variable usage

Tags: perl, dictionary, implicit, local-variables

This code compiles a set by way of hash keys of the unique basename stubs in a set of paths.

```
%stubs = map { $f=basename $_; $f =~ /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./ ; $1=>() } @pathlist;
```

Why do I need the `$f` references here? I thought I'd be ok with:

```
%stubs = map { basename; /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./; $1=>() } @pathlist;
```

But I get no match. Am I not permitted to modify $_ in the map block?

For those wondering what the code is doing:

For each $path (@pathlist), it's getting the basename, matching the first letter-number sequence, and then returning the first bracket match as the key on an empty list value. Example:

```
/some/dir/foo123.adfjijoijb
/some/dir/foo123.oibhobihe
/some/dir/bar789.popjpoj
```

returns

```
foo123 => ()
bar789 => ()
```

After which I use the keys of the map as the set of values so process.

Comment: I wonder about the `$1=>()` construct -- it returns 1-element list, and you're assigning to a *hash* so you must have an even-sized list. Try it: `perl -MData::Dumper -we 'my %hash = map { /(\d+)/;  $1 => () } 1..5; print Dumper(\%hash)'`

Answer (score 13):

basename does not default to acting on `$_`.  But you can match against its return value instead of using $f:

```
%stubs = map { basename($_) =~ /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./; $1 => undef } @pathlist;
```

Note that () in a list doesn't produce an element, it just flattens to nothing; you have to provide a value, even if only undef.  With `$1 => ()`, map iterations would alternate producing a key and a value for %stubs.

It's good to always check that your regex succeed before using $1:

```
%stubs = map { basename($_) =~ /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./ ? ($1 => undef) : () } @pathlist;
```

though if you don't mind the hash values being the empty string instead of undef, you can just make the regex match return the desired list:

```
%stubs = map { basename($_) =~ /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)()\./ } @pathlist;
```

Comment: @Dallaylaen: it occurs to me that you can do undef too: `/(something)()??/`

Comment: Excellent answer. The hash is merely there to produce set behaviour, i.e. to get unique stubs. Is there any rule about which functions default to acting on $_ and which don't?

Comment: @Phil H: most library functions (as opposed to builtins) do not default to $_ (though there are some that do);  for builtins, the ones where it makes any sense to default to $_ (though some were only made to recently, in 5.10: readpipe, unpack, and mkdir)

Comment: To further explain why you should check that the regex succeeds, consider what happens if it doesn't: A regex match sets the global `$1`, should the regex not find a match, `$1` will still contain the results of the previous match!

Comment: `perl -E '@a = qw/hi bye/; foreach (@a) { /(h.*)/; push @b, $1; } say for @b;'` gives: `hi\nhi\n`

Answer (score 6):

In map and grep, $_ is an alias for the values in the array.  If you modify them, you actually modify the values in the array.  This is probably not what you want and probably what is going wrong, but to debug print keys %stubs and @pathlist afterwards in both cases and let us know what it says.

Also: File::Basename's basename does not implicitly work on $_.  It generates an error for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use feature say;
use File::Basename;

@pathlist=("/some/dir/foo123.adfjijoijb","/some/dir/foo123.oibhobihe","/some/dir/bar789.popjpoj");
%stubs1 = map { $f=basename $_; $f =~ /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./ ; $1=>() } @pathlist;
say join(',',keys %stubs1);
say "---";
say join(',',@pathlist);
say "---";

%stubs = map { $_=basename $_; /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./; $1=>() } @pathlist;
say join(',',keys %stubs);
say "---";
say join(',',@pathlist);
say "---";

%stubs = map {basename; /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./; $1=>() } @pathlist;
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot that $_ is an alias. In this circumstance, it wouldn't matter as @pathlist is a throwaway list anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate implementation:

```
my %stubs =
   map { $_ => undef }
   map { basename($_) =~ /^([A-Za-z]+[0-9]+)\./ }
   @pathlist;
```